# Pagination products with filter parameters

Tags: php, sorting, pagination

I haven't been working with PHP for some time and now I have to solve a problem about statement of products with pagination and filtration (by price, by the newest ones etc).

This is my url example: `web.com/category-name` - when I want to paginate products, I use for this purpose the `$_GET` variable, like: `web.com/category-name?p=2`.

Now to this basic pagination I would need to add parameters for filtration.
My first idea would be to send form as `post` and the sent data for sorting save into the `SESSIONS` and always check, if the parameters for filtration are in `SESSION` and if they are, then I will filter products.

But I am not really sure that this solution is clean... I don't want to use `GET` for filter parameters, because there is a lot of possible parameters...

Can I ask you, how would you solve this situation?

Comment: I think there is no problem using `$_GET`. At least customer can copy-paste link to somebody with saved filter. I think it's user friendly.

Comment: It's actually good practice to have fileting in the URL, copy pasting the URL to a friend, would allow hotlinking to specific states of your page/site.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use POST and save parameters information inside hidden inputs, the problem with SESSION is that if an user closes the browser/tab and goes back it will be where it was instead of the beginning.

Also, if you use the same params in another module (like page=6) of the website it could show another results at page 6 instead of the first one.